# EmguCV VideoCapture no frame incoming after execution a while

Tags: c#, video-capture, emgucv

I'm facing an issue while using VideoCapture to display the screen from an HDMI capture card.

Initially, the video is displayed correctly, but after a while, the image freezed.
The ProcessFrame callback function is not being invoked.

Is there any issue with the code below?

```
    private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _capture = new VideoCapture(cbCamera.SelectedIndex);
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;

        if (_capture != null)
            _capture.Start();

        _IsCapturing = true;
    }

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        _capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
        picOutput.Image = frame;
        frame.Dispose();
    }
```

I've tried using different versions of EmguCV, but I still encounter the same issue.